# How to render different widgets depending on what button pressed

Tags: flutter

I created a list of item that are scrollable horizontally, and I am trying to render different widgets depending on what button is pressed. The widgets are created in different and independent files. What I need to achieve is to import them widgets depending on what button is pressed.
For example, that the widget of "DropDown" is rendered when the button of "DropDown" is pressed on the list.
The screen is the following:
[image]

Here is the code of the buttons list and where I should import the widgets:

```
class CategoryListState extends State<CategoryList> {

  int selectedIndex = 0;
  List categories = ['Checkboxes', 'DropDown', 'SwipeCards', 'SwipeCards', 'SwipeCards', 'SwipeCards',];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 20.0/2),
      height: 30.0,
      child: ListView.builder(
        scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
        itemCount: categories.length,
        itemBuilder: (context, index) => GestureDetector(
          onTap: () {
            setState(() {
              selectedIndex = index;
            });
          },
          child: Container (
            alignment: Alignment.center,
            margin: EdgeInsets.only(
              left: 20.0,
              right: index == categories.length -1 ? 20.0 : 0,
            ),
            padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20.0),
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              color: index == selectedIndex
                  ? Colors.white.withOpacity(0.4)
                  : Colors.transparent,
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(6),
            ),
            child: Text(
              categories[index].toString(),
              style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a list of widgets that you have created in different files and give it as a child wherever you need to change the content depending on the button pressed.

You could do something like this:

```
class CategoryListState extends State<CategoryList> {

  int selectedIndex = 0;
  List categories = ['Checkboxes', 'DropDown', 'SwipeCards', 'SwipeCards', 'SwipeCards', 'SwipeCards',];

//Your list of widgets that you import, note: keep the order same as categories
  List<Widget> category_widgets = [checkboxes_widget, dropDown_widget, swipeCards_widget, swipeCards_widget, swipeCards_widget, swipeCards_widget,];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
       children: <Wdiget>[
             Container(
      margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 20.0/2),
      height: 30.0,
      child: ListView.builder(
        scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
        itemCount: categories.length,
        itemBuilder: (context, index) => GestureDetector(
          onTap: () {
            setState(() {
              selectedIndex = index;
            });
          },
          child: Container (
            alignment: Alignment.center,
            margin: EdgeInsets.only(
              left: 20.0,
              right: index == categories.length -1 ? 20.0 : 0,
            ),
            padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20.0),
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              color: index == selectedIndex
                  ? Colors.white.withOpacity(0.4)
                  : Colors.transparent,
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(6),
            ),
            child: Text(
              categories[index].toString(),
              style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    ),
//Here the widget will be loaded when the selected_index changes i.e when you press a button the widget below will also change accordingly
      category_widgets[selected_index],
       ]
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [IndexedStack](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/IndexedStack-class.html) you basically need to change the index property

```
IndexedStack(
  index : 0,
  children : [

   child1, //shows when index is set to 0
   child2, //shows when index is set to 1
]
)
```